# Theoretically: Is there any advantage/reason on using a particular model for ML over another?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks

A neural network doesn't really care about the activation functions, and if we choose any activation function and a compatible loss, the model will converge into something. In a way, any model will be as good as another.

From this point of view, the only reason to pick a model over another would be the time spend to fit the data.

At the same time, say we have just one neuron, and we are fitting the classic of cat v non-cat with either linear or binary regression. But why would you choose any of them, if we can't really see the shape of the data, like we do in a plot?

Then, I assume the function itself is quite irrelevant.

I'm doing tests, but theoretically, would this be the same?

Comment: Yes, plenty of reasons. Related [Is linear regression obsolete?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305116/is-linear-regression-obsolete/305120?)

Comment: I think you missed the word "theoretically". @user2974951

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the [No free lunch theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem) or [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor).

Comment: sure, but simplicity isn't always the same for all of us @displayname

Answer (score 0):

> In a way, any model will be as good as another.

But models aren't as good as each other even when "kept the same".

Counter-examples:

- Neural networks and some other learners give a different result each time with training.
- Choice of network structure and activation functions can have a mathematically proven limitation on what functions the network is capable of learning.
- Often you try an arbitrary bunch of models and just pick the best one. And the best one could have been the best one just because of blind luck. But the model still "matters" since it got the best result, unless you would say it doesn't matter whether you won lotto or not because every ticket, winning or not, just contains lines of numbers.